# Upgrade from NH 1.2 to 2.1 and type="serializable" throwing serialization Exceptions

Tags: nhibernate

I have an old NH 1.2 project that I am updating to 2.1, and so far it's been a breeze, until I  hit a wall with properties that were mapped to type="serializable" and sql server 2000.

I keep getting serializationExceptions and the inner exception is complaining that it cannot find the assembly for 1.2.

Is it even possible to update to 2.1 in this regard? I have seen some posts discussing setting the column length, but no avail.

```
<property name="Lines"  type="Serializable"  >
  <column name="Lines" not-null="false" sql-type="varbinary(max)"/>
</property>
```

Is it merely a configuration issue, or am I likely to be hosed for existing data?

Edit:
I have also tried entering an assembly redirect in the off chance it might work. No love there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question and not removing it for posterity.

If you run into this SerializationException while attempting to deserialize, where the inner exception is clearly looking for an older version of the NHibernate assembly, it is because the property you serialized either is an NHibernate proxy itself, or has a NHibernate proxy in it's graph.

Moral of the story: Be darned careful what you set to type="serializable" in your maps.